# Put number first function respond with this: Promise { <pending> }

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am using the following function to put some data into dynamo DB table but I am getting this response that **Put number first function responds with this: Promise { pending }**
Here is the code

```
 async function putNumberFirst(phoneNumber) {
         return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
          console.log("inside put Numer function");
             let params = {
                 TableName: process.env.CHAT_DATA_TABLE,
                 Item: {
                     'phoneNumber': phoneNumber
                 }

             };
             console.log("PARAMS", params);
             docClient.put(params, function(err, results) {
                 if (err) {
                     console.error(
                         "Unable to put new connection data. Error:",
                         JSON.stringify(err, null, 2)
                     );
                     reject();
                 }
                 else {
                     console.log("Put succeeded.", results);
                     resolve("Success!");
                 }
             });
         });

     }
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: I expect that you declare the function as `exports.handler = async function putNumberFirst`, in the file, if so, what are the logs you are getting?

Comment: Actually, it is a function that is being called inside a lambda, exports.handler already been written in the lambda,
this function is inside that lambda

Comment: You are mixing async functions, promises, and callbacks. Choose just one.

Comment: Also, how did you get `Promise { pending }`? Is it from `console.log(putNumberFirst(phoneNumber))`?

Comment: Where did you call `putNumberFirst` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing up async functions, promises and callbacks. I suggest you try to understand these very important topics first: https://towardsdev.com/callback-vs-promises-vs-async-await-29572e4a0c8

Here's my **editorialized** `async/await` take on your code sample:

```
const putNumberFirst = async (phoneNumber) => {
  const params = {
      TableName: process.env.CHAT_DATA_TABLE,
      Item: { phoneNumber }
  };

  try {
      console.log("Params: ", params);
      const results = await docClient.put(params).promise();
      console.log('Put succeeded: ', results);
      return results;
  } catch (err) {
      console.error('Unable to put new connection data. Error:', JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
      throw err;
  }
}
```

Then, from wherever you want to call the `putNumberFirst` function, you need to await the response:

```js
await putNumberFirst(number);
```

Please keep in mind that `await` is available only in `async` functions, you may have to restructure your code accordingly.

You could use `then/catch` or a callback instead of `async/await`, but please, do not mix these things up unless absolutely necessary. Async code is the bread and butter of JS, it's absolutely critical that you understand how it works. Invest some time into it, it will be worth it.